# Conditional distribution of multivariate normal

Tags: probability-distributions

$X \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$. How can I find conditional distribution of $X$ given $AX$, where $A$ is a non-random matrix? I know that $AX \sim N(A\mu, A\Sigma A^T)$ but don't know what to do next.

P.S - I am preparing for an exam and solving problems from textbook, so should i add hashtag self-study?

Comment: What do you mean by "definite matrix"?

Comment: I want to say it is not random. I am sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Are there some more assumptions on A e.g. invertible, full rank or something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
X \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)
$$
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} X \\ AX \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} I \\ A \end{bmatrix} X & = BX \sim N(B\mu, B\Sigma B^T) = N\left( \begin{bmatrix} \mu \\ A\mu \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma & \Sigma A^T \\ A\Sigma & A\Sigma A^T \end{bmatrix} \right) \\[10pt]
& = N\left( \begin{bmatrix} \mu_1 \\ \mu_2 \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12} \\ \Sigma_{12}^T & \Sigma_{22} \end{bmatrix} \right)
\end{align}

Do you know how to find the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$ when it's written in that form? (The conditional variance is a Schur complement.)

Comment: Yes I know that! Thank you very much!

Comment: @MarkoffChainz : I'm glad it helps.